# What I have to change in cycles?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I want the word car to be written as many times as the number of letters of the word hello.

```
word = str(input('Enter something to secure: '))    #answer: car
password = str(input('Enter password: '))            #answer: hello   
y = []
for character in word:
    while True:
        i = character
        y.append(i)
        if len(y) == len(password):
            break
    print(y)
```

I want this to be printed:

> ['c','a','r','c','a']

Unfortunately this will be printed:

> ['c','c','c','c','c']

Comment: Have you tried switching the `for` loop and the `while` loop?

Comment: You are doing your while loop inside your for loop. You get the first character from car and then just loop on it. Try tracing the program in your head and you see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.cycle`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import cycle
word = str(input('Enter something to secure: '))    #answer: car
password = str(input('Enter password: '))            #answer: hello   
y = []
word = cycle(word)
for character in password:
    y.append(word.next())
print(y)
```

---

or

```
y = [word.next() for character in password]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through the `password` instead and print the `word` character one-by-one. You could loop back to the beginning of the `word` character by using `%`

```
word = str(input('Enter something to secure: '))
password = str(input('Enter password: '))
y = []
for i in range(len(password)):
    y.append(word[i%len(word)]) # loop through word characters
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, instead of using multiple loops.

```
word = str(input('Enter something to secure: '))    
password = str(input('Enter password: '))            
index = len(word)
output = []
for i in range(0, len(password)):
    output.append(word[i%index])
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it with lesser loops and may be better performance

```
word = str(input('Enter something to secure: '))
password = str(input('Enter password: '))
print((word*(len(password)//len(word)+1))[:len(password)])
```